# Back wheel spins

Tags: wheels

The back wheel on my grandson's 12 inch Spiderman bike is spinning nothing seems to be wrong the chain is not off and the training wheels are on right what could be the problem

Comment: Not being rude here, I understand It's often difficult to articulate a problem. You say the back wheel is spinning but that doesn't really mean much as that exactly what wheels are meant to do. Could you post a video of the problem?

Comment: Do you mean you are pedaling but no force is transmitted to the rear wheel? If the chain is on and the cogs in the back are turning it’s probably a broken freewheel mechanism in the rear hub.

Comment: Could be the trainer wheels are lower than they should and the rear wheel is lifted slightly of the ground

Comment: It sounds like you're describing what Dan K suggests -- the wheel spins but doesn't touch the pavement because the training wheels are improperly adjusted.